What checksum is suppose to be in $packageArgs.checksum chocolateyInstall script if the msi in included in the choco package?
If the msi is included in the choco package, is $packageArgs.checksum the msi checksum? Is this checksum only required if the msi is downloaded off the internet? Does choco install use this checksum automatically to verify the msi?

What checksum is supposed to be in $packageArgs.checksum if the MSI is included?
This is hugely specific to a package you are seeing and that we cannot see.
At a guess: The checksum provided as checksum should be the checksum of the file path in $packageArgs.url or $packageArgs.file.
Do I need a checksum?
Chocolatey itself doesn't require a checksum to create a package. If you're creating a package for your own (or business) use, you don't need it!
That said, the Chocolatey Community Repository (which is a popular repository to submit packages to) has moderation standards, and runs something called Package Validator against all packages that are submitted to it.
If you submit a package to the Chocolatey Community Repository, you will be asked to add a checksum if your package downloads the installer from the internet.
If you ship the installer in the package, you'll be asked instead to provide a Verification text file that describes how you can check the file is identical to the intended file - this often contains a checksum.
Does choco install use this checksum to verify the file?
This depends on the package, and/or what's being used in the chocolateyInstall.ps1 script.
Some Chocolatey functions do validate the checksum if you pass it, even with a local file.
These include:

Get-ChocolateyWebFile
Install-ChocolateyPackage (which calls Get-ChocolateyWebFile)
Install-ChocolateyVsixPackage (which calls Get-ChocolateyWebFile)
Install-ChocolateyZipPackage (which calls Get-ChocolateyWebFile)

